# Setting DIV height based on height of absolutely positioned child IMG

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I have a relatively positioned div with a number of absolutely positioned images within. 
The div and image are both set with a width of 100% to fill the layout (which is fluid), but I need to be able to set the height of the parent DIV so that it will show the whole image.

I've tried approaches similar to [CSS - relative positioned parent div not stretching to absolute child div height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184919/css-relative-positioned-parent-div-not-stretching-to-absolute-child-div-height) and [Resize parent div to match absolutly positioned child div height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359574/resize-parent-div-to-match-absolutly-positioned-child-div-height), but the height of the child image is return as 0.

I've even tried clearfixes, even though I'm not using floats.
Absolute positioning is required for these images, so I can't resolve with floats.

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/sdowswell/XmVu7/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="banner">
    <a href="newpage.html"><img src="images/banners/image1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="othernewpage.html"><img src="images/banners/image2.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#banner {
    width:100%; 
    position:relative; 
}

#banner>a>img {
    width:100%; 
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#banner').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $('#banner img')
            .css('position', 'absolute')
            .css('display', 'none');
    $('#banner img').first().css('display', 'block');
});
```

​

(Editted to get rid of irrelevant extra stuff. Editted again to include jQuery.)

Comment: Did you try finding the height of the `<a>` tag instead?

Comment: please edit to reproduce your issue - http://jsfiddle.net/L9Cqg/

Comment: You're using `id="container"` in the HTML, but `#banner` in the CSS. Should I assume both refer to the same id?

Comment: Forked and updated fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/sdowswell/XmVu7/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution by setting the #banner height after the first image had completed loading

```
$(window).load(function() {
     $('#banner').css('height', $('#banner img:first').css('height'))
});
```

(used window.load to ensure chrome's gathers info from fully loaded image)

It's not ideal, but it's doing the trick for now.